# 'conda update --all' yields different results on different machines

Tags: python, python-3.x, miniconda

'conda update -all' yields different results on different machines:
**Old HP Laptop/Win10** ca 2007, fresh install of miniconda and a few packages, and update-all a few days ago.
**Versions:**
pandas, numpy, numba:  ('1.4.1', '1.20.3', '0.54.1')
Python  3.9.12
ipython 8.2.0
conda  4.12.0

**2014 MacBook Air**, older miniconda install, same packages, update -all today
**Versions:**
pandas, numpy, numba:  ('1.3.4', '1.21.5', '0.55.1')
Python 3.7.13
ipython 7.20.0
conda 4.12.0

I am not an expert but why is one update quite a bit behind the other? Is it because of Mac vs PC? Would a install and reinstall help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#updating-or-upgrading-python), the result of running `conda update python` depends on which Python version is installed in the current environment. Python will be updated to the latest micro version of that version, but not to a later version.

For example, on your MacBook, you evidently ran the command in a Python 3.7.x environment, so it was updated to 3.7.13, which is the latest micro version of Python 3.7 (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python)). To get another version instead, the recommended way is to set up a new environment. When creating an environment, you can specify the Python version you want:
`conda create --name my_environment python=3.9`

The other packages are of course depending on the Python installation, so for example pandas was updated to version 1.3.4 on your MacBook, because I suppose this is the latest version that does not require Python 3.8+. But this dependency management can get very tricky, which is why setting up a new environment is recommended.

Comment: Indeed. The Mac was on 3.7.x. I had assumed an 'update -all' does the same as a fresh install, i.e. updates to the max. There is no recommended way to do that(?) For me, the easiest was to uninstall and install fresh and all the latest versions appeared.

Comment: You can of course uninstall and install fresh, but the problem is that if you then discover that some of the code you have written for the earlier Python and package versions no longer runs correctly because of something being deprecated, you don't have a way to run it in the original environment anymore.

Comment: Understood but I have a system to it, I do annual updates. First upgrade another machine where I test and remediate all my code before migrating it to my main, python-updated (or reinstalled) computer. The HP was the the test environment.